# R: create new variable, the new value are not correct

Tags: r, variables

I am creating a new variable "HS" to summarizing 4 variables "HS_A/B/C/D" in "data1" using:

```
HS <- rep(5,length(data1))
attach(data1)
HS[ HS_A == 2 & HS_B == 2 & HS_C==2 & HS_D==2 ] <- 0

HS[ HS_A == 1 & HS_B == 2 & HS_C==2 & HS_D==2 ] <- 1
HS[ HS_B == 1 & HS_A == 2 & HS_C==2 & HS_D==2 ] <- 2
HS[ HS_C == 1 & HS_A == 2 & HS_B==2 & HS_D==2 ] <- 3
HS[ HS_D == 1 & HS_A == 2 & HS_B==2 & HS_C==2 ] <- 4
hs1<-data.frame(HS_A,HS_B,HS_C,HS_D,HS)
```

I want all other values in `HS` are `5`, if they are not 0/1/2/3/4, so I just use `rep` 5. 
The problem is that, some values in `HS` are `NA`, whereas I think they should be `5`.

there is no `NA` in `data1`, and I have checked the rows with `HS` of `NA` using (`which(!!rowSums(is.na(hs)))`). `#[1] 1545 1646 1687 1744 1784 1817` and they are "`1212NA`" "`1112NA`" "`1112NA`" "`1112NA`""`1112NA`""`1112NA`".

Can anyone help to explain why? and is there any way to solve or simpler way to create the variable?

Also is how to do the new variable in a `for` loop?

I am new to R.
Thanks,
Qiqi

Comment: Could you show few rows of `data1` YOu should use `is.na(HS)` instead of `HS==NA` if they are real `NAs` and not strings.

Comment: Do you have NA values in `data1`?

Comment: Even if you don't have NA's I guess my code below should work.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Here is an example without `NA`; `set.seed(225);
data2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:3, 4*1500, replace=TRUE), 
                 ncol=4, dimnames=list(NULL, paste("HS", LETTERS[1:4], sep="_"))) )` applying the code below, I am getting the expected results. `any(!!rowSums(is.na(data2)))#[1] FALSE`

Comment: I would assume your `NA` are actually `characters`. For example `set.seed(345);
data1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("NA", 1:3), 4*20, replace=TRUE), 
               ncol=4, dimnames=list(NULL, paste("HS", LETTERS[1:4], sep="_")))); 
 
 indx <- as.character(interaction(data1, sep=''))`  If it were actual `NAs`, the `indx` would be just `NA` for that row.

Comment: @akrun thanks for your kindness. my NAs are NAs and your code do work. but my main problem is that the NAs should be "5", rather than NA or "NA". I want those A=1, B=1, C=1, D=2 turns to HS=5, but now they are NA.

Comment: In the example I created, the NAs are replaced by `5` for the `HS` column.  if you look at the code.  Can you paste the `dput` output of the subset of your dataset which shows this anomaly?  ie. `dput(data1[1:20,])`

Comment: I tried different combinations, but I couldn't get any `NAs` in the HS column after the code was run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i found out the problem. it was dumb. `HS <- rep(5,length(data1))` is not correct. it should be `HS <- rep(5,nrow(data1))` coz `length` is the number of variables.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming that there are `NA` values in the original dataset `data1`.  So, if a row contains `NA` value, any of the conditions specified will become `FALSE` and will get a value of `5`.  There might be also cases where the combinations between columns return FALSE for the conditions, which are also given `5`.

```
  indx <- as.character(interaction(data1, sep=''))
  lvls <- c('2222', '1222', '2122', '2212', '2221')
  indx[!indx %in% lvls] <- 6
  data1$HS <- as.numeric(factor(indx, levels=c(lvls,6)))-1
```

Here is a glimpse of `data1`

```
  lapply(split(data1, data1$HS), head,2)
  #$`0`
  #      HS_A HS_B HS_C HS_D HS
  #1029    2    2    2    2  0
  #1064    2    2    2    2  0

  #$`1`
  #    HS_A HS_B HS_C HS_D HS
  #164    1    2    2    2  1
  #661    1    2    2    2  1

  #$`2`
  #    HS_A HS_B HS_C HS_D HS
  #46     2    1    2    2  2
  #211    2    1    2    2  2

  #$`3`
  #    HS_A HS_B HS_C HS_D HS
  #349    2    2    1    2  3
  #429    2    2    1    2  3

  #$`4`
  #    HS_A HS_B HS_C HS_D HS
  #152    2    2    2    1  4
  #307    2    2    2    1  4

  #$`5`
  #   HS_A HS_B HS_C HS_D HS
  #1   NA    2    3    1  5
  #2    1    3   NA    2  5
```

#### data

```
  set.seed(345)
  data1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 4*1500, replace=TRUE), 
                 ncol=4, dimnames=list(NULL, paste("HS", LETTERS[1:4], sep="_"))) )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `which(HS==NA)` you are cunfused about how the "==" function handles NA. The reason for the existence of `is.na` is that nothing equals NA. Using the somewhat bloated example of akrun you can see how which() with arr.in=TRUE works:

```
 str( which(is.na(data1), arr.ind=TRUE))
#--------------------------
 int [1:1446, 1:2] 1 10 13 16 18 23 24 25 28 31 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "row" "col"
> head( which(is.na(data1), arr.ind=TRUE))
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]  10   1
[3,]  13   1
[4,]  16   1
[5,]  18   1
[6,]  23   1
```

I suspect the rest of the problem is how you are naming the values of data1. Using attach is a bad way to access columns. Using `with` or `transform` is safer.The other possibility is that you don't understand how "&" handles NA values.